# Spring MVC bulk message using MimeMessagePreparator

Tags: email, spring-mvc, bulk

I'm trying to send bulk emails using Spring MVC. Here is my code:

```
    if(customerClients != null){

        int count = 0;
        boolean sent = false;

        List<MimeMessagePreparator> preparators = new ArrayList<MimeMessagePreparator>();

        for (BulkEmail client : customerClients) {

            if(customerID==-1)
                customerID = client.getCustomerID();

            CustomerAccount customerAccount = service.getCustomerAccount(client.getCustomerID());

            if (instantMessage.isEmailChecked() && customerAccount.getBalance()>0) {

                try{
                    final String receiverID = client.getEmail();
                    instantMessage.setIpersonOrGroupValue(receiverID);

                     preparators.add(new MimeMessagePreparator() 
                        {
                            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception 
                            {
                                final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
                                message.setSubject(instantMessage.getSubject());
                                message.setTo(receiverID);
                                message.setFrom(from); 
                                message.setText(instantMessage.getMessage(), true);
                            }
                        });

                     sent = false;
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            ++count;

            if(count%100==0){
                springMail.send(preparators);
                preparators = new ArrayList<MimeMessagePreparator>();
                sent = true;
            }
        }

        if(!sent)
            springMail.send(preparators);
```

Here is the code that uses JavaMailSender for sending the preparators:

```
public void send(List<MimeMessagePreparator> preparatorsList) {
    MimeMessagePreparator[] preparators = preparatorsList.toArray(new MimeMessagePreparator[preparatorsList.size()]);
    mailSender.send(preparators);       
}
```

The problem with this code is it takes around 1 second per email address. This means 300 emails in 5 minutes.
I want to know if this is normal or there is something I can do to improve.

Thanks

Comment: I'm checking on to see if message queuing can help